# why body tag wont be 100% height

Tags: html, css

this is a very simple question, but not in the problem that i have now.
i know how to make `<body>` full screen. we give it a 100vh height and 100wh width.
i have a problem in this part. when i give `<body>` 100 height, it works. but when i give `margin-top` for example 20px to the first element of `<body>`, now the height of `<body>` wont fill all the height of the screen. [you can see it in this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eONSy.png)

the blue background is for `<body>`. in the picture, the first element in `<body>` is the hamburger icon and i gave that a 20px `margin-top` and 30px `margin-left` and as you can see, the body is not full height...
i am sure that i gave the body tag 100% height.

```
    <body>
    <div class="hamburger open">&#x2630</div>
    <div class="groups-mobile">
        <button class="create-group">create a group</button>
        <ul class="groups-list">
            <li class="group selected">saman<div class="justify-content-between" style="margin-left: 20px;"><i class="fas fa-edit edit"></i><i class="far fa-trash-alt remove"></i></div></li>
            <li class="group">saaaaammiii<div class="justify-content-between" style="margin-left: 20px;"><i class="fas fa-edit edit"></i><i class="far fa-trash-alt remove"></i></div></li>
            <li class="group">saaaammmm<div class="justify-content-between" style="margin-left: 20px;"><i class="fas fa-edit edit"></i><i class="far fa-trash-alt remove"></i></div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    other tags....
    </body>
    


body {
    background: url("../images/matheus-cenali-3RicCdnXfHs-unsplash.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    height: 100vh;
}

body .hamburger {
font-size: 40px;
background-color:rgba(228, 228, 228, 0.7);
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
border-radius: 50%;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 30px;
```

}

please help me with this problem.

Comment: overflow:auto to body

Answer (score 0):

Since the `<body>` element much like every other element looks to its parent (`<html>`), you will need to apply a height to the `<html>` element.

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it didnt work and my body didnt fill all of my page...